# R subset column of data frame based on list of dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe

```
  PeopleId       Date NumItemsQuotes
     (dbl)     (time)          (dbl)
1        2 2015-10-26            147
2        2 2015-10-27              4
3        2 2015-10-28            268
4        2 2015-10-30             55
5        2 2015-11-02              1
6        2 2015-11-03              6
```

Given the above data frame, I want to subset this to just the observations which occur on a weekend. So far, I've created a vector of the weekends because its a small amount (only 5 weekends) but I'm stuck in this approach.

```
weekends<- as.Date(c("2015-10-24","2015-10-25","2015-10-30","2015-11-01","2015-11-07","2015-11-08","2015-11-14","2015-11-15","2015-11-21","2015-11-22"))

weekenders<-itemquote[,"PeopleId"][itemquote$Date == weekends]
```

In the interest of genuinely learning this concept - I could also create an index column from timeDate::isWeekend() and then drop false observations correct?

Any other suggestions for approaching this?

Comment: I would do `itemquote[chron::is.weekend(itemquote$Date), ]`.  By the way, Friday is not considered a weekend day.  Pretty sure chron comes with the base R install.

Comment: There is a function in `lubridate` called `wday` which does that

Comment: `format(x, '%w') %in% c('0','6')` or  `as.POSIXlt(x)$wday %in% c(0,6)` where `x` is the `Date` vector.

Comment: Thanks all! Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to your method using the object `weekends`, you could use `%in%`. So your code would be `weekenders<-itemquote[,"PeopleId"][itemquote$Date == weekends]` or in a shorter way:`weekenders <- subset(itemquote, Date %in% weekends)$PeopleId`.

Comment: Ok, that actually makes more sense. I knew there must be a way to use subset in this case so `%in%` really makes sense. Seems like its a more flexible answer too as I'm guessing it does not need to be a factor. Does this work for all date formats?

Comment: @gscott, what do you mean by "it" in " it does not need to be a factor"? `Date` oder `weekends`? And of what situations you are thinking about when asking about wheter it will work for all date formats? Try to give an example (and you might find out for yourselfe).